Exception calling "UploadFilePart" with "1" argument(s): "155"
I am trying to check-in a file into vault from my local, for that I need upload ticket, using this code in Powershell and getting a "155" exception.
can anyone help me to solve this?
function Upload-FileResource {
    param (
        [Object] $vault,
        [string] $filename,
        [byte[]] $fileContents
    )
    
    $headerObject = New-Object Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices.FileTransferHeader
    $headerObject.Identity = New-Guid
    $headerObject.Extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($filename)
    $headerObject.Vault = $vault.WebServiceCredentials.VaultName
    $uploadTicket = New-Object Autodesk.Connectivity.WebServices.ByteArray
    $bytesTotal = if ($null -ne $fileContents) { $fileContents.Length } else { 0 }
    $bytesTransferred = 0
    do {
        $bufferSize = $bytesTotal - $bytesTransferred
        if ($bufferSize -gt (49 * 1024 * 1024)) {
            $bufferSize = (49 * 1024 * 1024)
        }
 
        $buffer = $fileContents[$bytesTransferred..($bytesTransferred + $bufferSize - 1)]
        $headerObject.Compression = "None" 
        $headerObject.IsComplete = ($bytesTransferred + $bufferSize) -eq $bytesTotal
        $headerObject.UncompressedSize = $bufferSize
        $fileContentsStream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new($buffer)
        $uploadTicket.Bytes = $vault.FilestoreService.UploadFilePart($fileContentsStream)
        $bytesTransferred += $bufferSize
    } 
    while ($bytesTransferred -lt $bytesTotal)
    return $uploadTicket
}

$fileContents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($localPath)
$uploadTicket = Upload-FileResource -vault $vault -filename $fileName -fileContents $fileContents


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm not using Powershell,  but I had a look in the .Net documentation and found that error code 155 = "A null value was passed in where a null value is not allowed" . Seems you are passing null somewhere, hope that helps.

